# My Android app builds failed Hilt, WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I am trying to migrate from Dagger2 to Hilt following the reference: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager

But when I build my app, it fail with below error log:

```
/Users/.../myapp/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/devDebug/.../MyWorker.java:13: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
@error.NonExistentClass()
^
```

And here is the line 13:

```
line 11    @error.NonExistentClass()
line 12    public MyWorker(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
line 13    @error.NonExistentClass()
line 14    android.content.Context appContext, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
line 15    @error.NonExistentClass()
line 16    androidx.work.WorkerParameters params, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

I don't know how can I fix it...

What I using versions are:

```
// kotlin
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.21"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.21"

// Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.35"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

// WorkManager
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0"
implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:2.5.0"
```

These versions are the latest and stable versions.

---

I tried to add the below Gradle setting but it's same error...

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

Comment: probably a version compatibility issue. Whats on `MyWorker:Line13` ?

Comment: @ADM I update the line 13 info

Comment: Please show the actual line 13

Comment: Please attach your WorkManager code

Answer (score 2):

Whooooooooo.....

I found the cause...

I'm sorry for all...

I am Korean, so I have been watching this guidance document for the Korean version: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack

But I found it is too old!

It guides to use `@WorkerInject` in the Korean version,
But it guides to use `@AssistedInject` in the English version...

When I change it, the error disappeared...